# Visitor pattern implementation in case of source code un-availability

Tags: java, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

One of the reasons to consider the [Visitor_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

> A practical result of this separation is the ability to add new operations to existing object structures without modifying those structures.

Assume that you don't have the source code of third party libraries and you have added one operation on related objects.

Since you don't have object, your elements (Third party classes) can't be modified to add Visitor.

In this case, double dispatch is not possible.

So which option is generally preferred?

*`Option 1:`*  Extend one more inheritance hierarchy on top of third party class and implement pattern as show in picture with double dispatch?

For a given hierarchy of Class B which extends Class A, you can add

```
ElementA extends A
ElementB extends B
```

Now ConcreteElements are derived from ElementA instead of class A.

Cons: The number of classes will grow.

*`Option 2:`*  Use Visitor class a central helper class and get the work done with single dispatch.

Cons: We are not really following Visitor patter as per UML diagram.

Correct if I am wrong.

Comment: This is most definitely *not* the reason to use *any* pattern. And the visitor pattern isn't described by any UML diagram. In any case, without knowing what language you are talking about it's impossible to even discuss about implementations. Does the language support generics? Lambdas? Does it have dynamic features? All of these allow you to create a Visitor that doesn't need double dispatch

Comment: I have provided some more context and language (java) details

Comment: @AdityaW what is the use-case/user-story you are going to implement?

Comment: One abstract method has to be added to the base class and derived classes have to implement it. Assume that you dont have soruce code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, which reason is not "the reason"? The question starts quoting a reason, from external source, which seems reasonable

Comment: @zameb the reason to use any pattern is because you have the problem it solves and the specific circumstances where the pattern applies. Not because you think it may be needed. The definition of a pattern is `A Solution to a Problem in a Context`. Not `common best practice`. Besides, if someone asked what pattern can add new operations to an existing structure, the first pattern that came to mind would be `Command`, not `Visitor`

Comment: @zameb the Wikipedia article isn't wrong. A *result/side-effect* of applying Visitor is that new operations are possible up to a point. The same applies for a *lot* of patterns though, while solving very different problems.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, in my case, Decorator, Strategy, Facade comes before Command. Because I see complicated to add a Command to an existing structure without violating the Open-Close principle. I understand a Command as the complete behavior as a class, not part of another class (existing structure). In fact, I think RelayCommand and DelegateCommand (WPF) implementations, are nice commodities but violates a lot of SOLID principles... but of course there may be a more open perspective than mine

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could combine a **Wrapper** and  **Visitor** to solve your problems.
Using the wrapper to **add** a `visit` method allows you to increase the usability of these objects. Of course you get the full advantages (less dependency on the legacy classes) and disadvantages (additional objects) of a wrapper.

---

Here's a worked-up example in JAVA (because it is pretty strict, does not do double-dispatch by itself, and I'm quite familiar with it):

## 1) Your legacy Objects

Assuming you have your legacy objects `Legacy1` and `Legacy2`which you *cannot* change, which have specific business methods:

```
public final class Legacy1 {
    public void someBusinessMethod1(){
        ...
    }
}
```

and

```
public final class Legacy2 {
    public void anotherBusinessMethod(){
        ...
    }
}
```

## 2) Prepare the Wrapper

You just wrap them in a **VisitableWrapper** which has a `visit` method that takes your **visitor**, like:

```
public interface VisitableWrapper {
    public void accept(Visitor visitor);
}
```

With the following implementations:

```
public class Legacy1Wrapper implements VisitableWrapper {

    private final Legacy1 legacyObj;

    public Legacy1Wrapper(Legacy1 original){
        this.legacyObj = original;
    }

    public void accept(Visitor visitor){
         visitor.visit(legacyObj);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Legacy2Wrapper implements VisitableWrapper {

    private final Legacy2 legacyObj;

    public Legacy2Wrapper(Legacy2 original){
        this.legacyObj = original;
    }

    public void accept(Visitor visitor){
         visitor.visit(legacyObj);
    }
}
```

## 3) Visitor, at the ready!

Then your own **Visitor**s can be set to visit the wrapper like so:

```
public interface Visitor {
     public void visit(Legacy1 leg);
     public void visit(Legacy2 leg);
}
```

With an implementation like so:

```
public class SomeLegacyVisitor{

    public void visit(Legacy1 leg){
        System.out.println("This is a Legacy1! let's do something with it!");
        leg.someBusinessMethod1();
    }

    public void visit(Legacy2 leg){
        System.out.println("Hum, this is a Legacy 2 object. Well, let's do something else.");
        leg.anotherBusinessMethod();
    }
}
```

## 4) Unleash the power

Finally in your code, this framework would work like this:

```
public class TestClass{
    // Start off with some legacy objects
    Legacy1 leg1 = ...
    Legacy2 leg2 = ...

    // Wrap all your legacy objects into a List:
    List<VisitableWrapper> visitableLegacys = new ArrayList<>();
    visitableLegacys.add(new Legacy1Wrapper(legacy1));
    visitableLegacys.add(new Legacy2Wrapper(legacy2));

    // Use any of your visitor implementations!
    Visitor visitor = new SomeLegacyVisitor();
    for(VisitableWrapper wrappedLegacy: visitableLegacys){
        wrappedLegacy.accept(visitor);
    }
}
```

The expected output:

```
This is a Legacy1! let's do something with it!
Hum, this is a Legacy 2 object. Well, let's do something else.
```

**Drawbacks:**

1. Quite a lot of boilerplate. Use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) if you develop in Java.
2. Quite a lot of wrapper objects instances. May or may not be a problem for you.
3. You need to know the specific type of the objects beforehand. This implies you know their subtype, they aren't bundles in a List. If that's the case, you have no other option but to use reflection.

Comment: I worked this up in Rust using the same approach, may not be idiomatic Rust but I wanted to give it a try as I'm learning Rust.  See https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=f7b16a26a85de5661564388a41d274e5

Comment: This one is idiomatic to Rust, much simpler: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=b92bbc84f3c17ea38eab742c354f4606

Comment: This one maintains the ability to add visitors "on the fly".  Basically the same as the Java version except the object wrappers aren't needed: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=c0203c3260209dc69a5d0b30b4e5fc7b

Comment: Using an enum; probably the simplest and most idiomatic, maintains ability to define visitors "on the fly": https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=2fd179da6b0064763fa3fbd7c34e10cb

Answer (score 0):

There should be a possibility to add new functionality to the classes of some hierarchy, without changing the base class interface. Kinds of possible behavior should be constant, while operations for different classes should execute differently.

The **Visitor Pattern** allows to concentrate all that operations in one class. There might be a lot of `Concrete Element` classes (from the diagram), but for each of them there will be implemented `visit()` method in `Concrete Visitor` class that will define his own algorithm.

Definition and implementation of method for each subclass of `Element` class:

```
public interface Visitor {
    void visit(Element element);
}

public class ConcreteVisitor implements Visitor {
    public void visit(Element element) {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

The **Visitor Pattern** is easily extended for new operations by implementing this interface by new class with his method implementation.

The following structure encapsulates the `Element` class:

```
public lass ObjectStructure {
    private Element element;
    // some methods
}
```

This `ObjectStructure` class could aggregate one or several instances of `Element`. Presentation that `Visitor` acts on:

```
public interface Element {
    void accept(Visitor visitor);
}
```

And implementation of `accept()` method in the concrete entity:

```
public class ConcreteElement implements Element {
    public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit();
    }
}
```

Using of **Visitor Pattern** allows to save `Element` hierarchy from huge logical functionality or complicated configuration.

It is desirable to add the functionality to all the classes of hierarchy while defining a new `Visitor` subclasses. But there could be a problem: `visit()` *should be overriden for every hierarchy type*. To avoid this it's better to define `AbstractVisitor` class and all leave his all `visit()` method bodies empty.

**Conclusion:** using this pattern is good when class hierarchy of type `Element` keeps constant. If new classes add, it usually goes to considerable changes in classes of `Visitor` type.

Comment: Still you did not address my query on source code un-availability. I can't add accept and visit methods in hierarchy of classes.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very similar to Michael von Wenckstern's, with the improvements that we have a named `accept` method (more like the standard pattern) and that we handle unknown concrete classes -- there's no guarantee that at some point a concrete implementation we haven't seen before won't appear on the classpath.
My visitor also allows a return value.

I've also used a more verbose name for the `visit` methods -- including the type in the method name, but this isn't necessary, you can call them all `visit`.

```
// these classes cannot be modified and do not have source available

class Legacy {
}

class Legacy1 extends Legacy {
}
class Legacy2 extends Legacy {
}

// this is the implementation of your visitor    

abstract class LegacyVisitor<T> {
    abstract T visitLegacy1(Legacy1 l);
    abstract T visitLegacy2(Legacy2 l);

    T accept(Legacy l) {
        if (l instanceof Legacy1) {
            return visitLegacy1((Legacy1)l);
        } else if (l instanceof Legacy2) {
            return visitLegacy2((Legacy2)l);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknown concrete Legacy subclass:" + l.getClass());
        }
    }
}
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = new LegacyVisitor<String>() {

            @Override
            String visitLegacy1(Legacy1 l) {
                return "It's a 1";
            }

            @Override
            String visitLegacy2(Legacy2 l) {
                return "It's a 2";
            }
        }.accept(new Legacy1());

        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I had to made a few assumptions about the legacy code, since you didn't provide much details about it. Let's say I need to add a new method to `Legacy` without reimplementing everything. This is how I'll do it:

```
public interface LegacyInterface {
    void A();
}

public final class LegacyClass implements LegacyInterface {
    @Override
    public void A() {
        System.out.println("Hello from A");
    }
}
```

First extends the "contract"

```
public interface MyInterface extends LegacyInterface {
    void B();
}
```

And implement it in a "[decorated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)" way

```
public final class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    private final LegacyInterface origin;

    public MyClass(LegacyInterface origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    @Override
    public void A() {
        origin.A();
    }

    @Override
    public void B() {
        System.out.println("Hello from B");
    }
}
```

The key point is `MyInterface extends LegacyInterface`: this is the **guarantee** the implementations will benefit from both the services from the legacy code and your personnal addings.

Usage

```
MyInterface b = new MyClass(new LegacyClass());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is the *`Option 1:`* Extend one more inheritance hierarchy on top of third party class and implement the visitor pattern with double dispatch.

The problem is the number of additional classes you need, but this can be resolved with a dynamic wrapper decorator. 
The Wrapper Decorator is a way to add interface implementation, methods and properties to already existing obejcts: [How to implement a wrapper decorator in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595221/how-to-implement-a-wrapper-decorator-in-java)

In this way you need your `Visitor` interface and put there the `visit(L legacy)` methods:

```
public interface Visitor<L> {
    public void visit(L legacy);
}
```

In the AcceptInterceptor you can put the code for the accept method

```
public class AcceptInterceptor {

    @RuntimeType
    public static Object intercept(@This WrappedAcceptor proxy, @Argument(0) Visitor visitor) throws Exception {
        visitor.visit(proxy);
    }
}
```

The `WrappedAcceptor` interface defines the method to accept a visitor and to set and retrieve the wrapped object

```
interface WrappedAcceptor<V> {
   Object getWrapped();
   void setWrapped(Object wrapped);
   void accept(V visitor); 
}
```

And finally the utility code to create the Wrapper around any obect:

```
Class<? extends Object> proxyType = new ByteBuddy()
 .subclass(legacyObject.getClass(), ConstructorStrategy.Default.IMITATE_SUPER_TYPE_PUBLIC)
 .method(anyOf(WrappedAcceptor.class.getMethods())).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(AcceptInterceptor.class))
 .defineField("wrapped", Object.class, Visibility.PRIVATE)
 .implement(WrappedAcceptor.class).intercept(FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty())
 .make()
 .load(getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
 .getLoaded();
WrappedAcceptor wrapper = (WrappedAcceptor) proxyType.newInstance();
wrapper.setWrapped(legacyObject);
```

Answer (score -1):

If your library does not has `accept` methods you need to do it with `instanceof`. (Normally you do twice single-dispatching in Java to emulate double dispatching; but here we use `instanceof` to emulate double dispatching).

Here is the example:

```
interface Library {
  public void get1();
  public void get2();
}

public class Library1 implements Library {
  public void get1() { ... }
  public void get2() { ... }
}

public class Library2 implements Library {
  public void get1() { ... }
  public void get2() { ... }
}

interface Visitor {
   default void visit(Library1 l1) {}
   default void visit(Library2 l2) {}

   default void visit(Library l) {
      // add here instanceof for double dispatching
      if (l instanceof Library1) {
          visit((Library1) l);
      }
      else if (l instanceof Library2) {
          visit((Library2) l);
      }
   }
}

// add extra print methods to the library
public class PrinterVisitor implements Visitor {
   void visit(Library1 l1) {
       System.out.println("I am library1");
   } 
   void visit(Library2 l2) {
       System.out.println("I am library2");
   }        
}
```

and now in any method you can write:

```
Library l = new Library1();
PrinterVisitor pv = new PrinterVisitor();
pv.visit(l);
```

and it will print to you "I am library1";

Comment: Still you did not address my query on source code un-availability. I can't add accept and visit methods in hierarchy of classes