# What is the usage of the IVisitable interface in Visitor Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Im really trying to understand the importance of this interface, but beside helping us to write more quickly, the methods in the concrete classes (by only implementing the methods) I just can't find the need to use it.

The definition is this

> an abstraction which declares the accept operation. This is the
>   entry point which enables an object to be "visited" by the visitor
>   object.
>   Each object from a collection should implement this abstraction in
>   order to be able to be visited

."
Its clear, but still you can manualy write those accept methods in every single class(which is lot of unnecessary work I agree) but still beside that you can get a class to be visitable, without the IVisitable interface...

```
//IVisitable.java
package Visitor;

/**
*
* @author dragan
*/
public interface IVisitable {                 
    public void accept (Visitor v); 
}
```

// Bgirl.java

```
public class Bgirl implements  IVisitable{

    int _br_godina;

    public Bgirl(int g) {
        br_godina = g;
    }

    public int getBr_godina() {
        return _br_godina;
    }

    public void accept (Visitor v){        
        v.visit(this);            
    }

}
```

//  Main.java

```
package Visitor;

/**
*
* @author dragan
*/
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Bgirl terra = new Bgirl(5);  

        System.out.println(terra.getBr_godina());

        VisitorImplement v = new VisitorImplement();              

    }  
}
```

//  VisitorImplement.java

```
package Visitor;

/**
 *
 * @author dragan
 */
public class VisitorImplement implements Visitor{

    @Override
    public void visit(Bgirl prva) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

      prva._br_godina = 3;

    }

//    @Override
//    public void visit(Bboy prvi) {
//       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
//        System.out.println("BBOY VISIT");
//    
//    }
//    


}
```

Comment: please look here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39174843/4390212

Comment: Could you please show us the IVistable interface and the source of the definition? There are two interfaces involved in the visitorpattern that I know, For example at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Comment: so from what i understand, its usefull when you have an array of different object, and you can call the accept method through polymorphism?

Comment: You don´t need an array of different objects for a good example of the visitor pattern. You need two different operations on some different classes which allow visiting / implement IVistable.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html source

Comment: Your question sounds almost as if you're asking why you would want to use interfaces in most design patterns -- what is the benefit of this abstraction. If so, then you'll want to get and read a good book on design patterns such as the Gang of Four book or the Heads Up book.

Answer (score 0):

Look into your `main()` method: you can just directly call `terra._br_godina = 3` and thus no need to use any visitor.

A visitor is useful when you don't know the concrete type of your `terra` and even don't know which method should be called to fullfil your wish. All you have is just an abstract type or interface e.g.  `Girl` (or `IVisitable`). So, to demonstrate the usefulness of Visitor Pattern, your `main()` method should be like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IVisitable terra = new Bgirl(5);
    // Want to set _br_godina of terra to 3 but do not and cannot know
    // which method should be called
    // Let's create a visitor and let him visit her,
    // he knows how to set _br_godina of her to 3
    VisitorImplement v = new VisitorImplement();
    terra.accept(v); // luckily, every girl accepts the "accept()"
}
```