# Processing an object depending on its implementation of an interface in Java

Tags: java

I have been looking for design ideas to solve this problem in Java.

I am using a library (**I cannot change it**) that for this example, I'll just call "Animals". It contains an **Animal** interface, and a bunch of implementations; and I need to call different methods according to the implementation of the Animal I get:

```
List<Animal> animals = Service.getAnimals();

for(Animal a : animals) {
    process(a);
}

private void process(Animal animal) {

    if (animal instanceOf Cat) {
        processCat(animal);
    } else if (animal instanceOf Dog) {
        processDog(animal);
    } else {
        System.out.println("unsopported animal");
    }
}
```

I am currently solving this through reflection, with a class that holds all "Processors" and calling them using

```
String methodName = "process" + Animal getClass().getSimpleName(); //ugh
```

I am using Java 8 and I am pretty sure there must be better design to address this issue.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Look up the "visitor" design pattern, as it can help you solve this

Comment: Which is the point of using an interface that doesn't contain the method you want to call? In any case the interface should have a common method, and each class implement it in a different way.

Comment: Other languages would call this pattern matching, in Java Visitor pattern would be the way to go.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Agreed if and only if you create the instances yourself. If the external service is providing you with a collection of opaque interface implementations then you're back to square one...

Comment: This totally contradicts the open closed principle btw animal should have an abstract function process and subclasses should implements that method(with different behaviour).

Comment: @user69513 Not at all. The Visitor pattern is non-intrusive. It doesn't require you to have control over the target object source code. That's one of its main features.

Comment: @EJP If you do not control the source code, and the source does not already have a method which accepts a `Visitor` object, and you also do not instantiate the base types yourself (but rather receive a collection of supertype objects), then I fail to see how you can avoid the check-and-cast pattern (or reflection) described by the asker.

Comment: You could also consider, Chain Of Responsibility. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern

Answer (score 9):

If Animal's is a sealed class, that is, it isn't dynamically extendable, and has a limited, known number of sub-classes, Then the if-instanceof pattern you have stumbled across in the example is classic "pattern matching".

If Animal was a class you could control, then you could use the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to create a visit method directly on Animal.

However you state that Animal is from an external library, which limits the approach you can take.

You can still use the Visitor pattern, keeping all code responsible for interacting with Animals in a single class, <s>using method overloading to resolve the type at runtime (assuming you don't have any issues with generics).</s>

But really this is just as inflexible as if-instanceof method, it just makes OO people feel better.

So, the approach to take comes down to code organization, and what makes sense for your code base.

Honestly, the if-instanceof is what I would go for, unless the amount of methods / behaviors starts getting too complex.

In which case, I'd create a type of registry, that registers a processor for each of the animal types.

Then, you can create a simple class that gets the required processor from the registry for the type of Animal.

This registry pattern I've seen used a lot in Minecraft, but I'm not sure if it's documented elsewhere.

Essentially it's use would look something like this.

```
void onApplicationStart(){
    Registry registry = new Registry();
    registry.register(Cat.class, cat -> catProcessor.process(cat));
    registry.register(Dog.class, dog -> dogProcessor.process(dog));
    registry.registerFallback(Animal.class, ani -> animalProcessor.process(ani));
}
```

Then later, you could fetch the registry, and the method that does the processing.

```
void whenNeeded(Animal animal){
    Registry registry = fetchRegistrySomehow();
    registry.for(animal.getClass()).apply(animal);
}
```

**Edit:**
The implementation of registry is deliberately missing, as exact behavior differs depending on how you want to do the lookup, treat class hierarchies, when and if the registry should be sealed after some application started event.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can hide you approach into beautiful candy wrapper, e.g. using `Enum` or `Class hierarchy` in case of many overroden methods.

E.g. this is two `Animal` implementation with different methods name to get animal's name:

```
class Dog implements Animal {

    public String getDogName() {
        return "dog";
    }
}

class Cat implements Animal {

    public String getCatName() {
        return "cat";
    }
}
```

Then you can define an `Enum`, with `Functions` for each implementation:

```
enum AnimalRegistry {
    DOG(Dog.class, animal -> ((Dog)animal).getDogName()),
    CAT(Cat.class, animal -> ((Cat)animal).getCatName());

    private final Class<? extends Animal> cls;
    private final Function<Animal, String> getName;

    AnimalRegistry(Class<? extends Animal> cls, Function<Animal, String> getName) {
        this.cls = cls;
        this.getName = getName;
    }

    public final String getName(Animal animal) {
        return getName.apply(animal);
    }

    public static AnimalRegistry parseClass(Animal animal) {
        for (AnimalRegistry registry : values())
            if (registry.cls == animal.getClass())
                return registry;
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown Animal implementation: " + animal.getClass().getSimpleName());    
    }
}
```

Finally, your client code could look like:

```
Animal animal = ...;
String animalName = AnimalRegistry.parseClass(animal).getName(animal);
```

Repeat, that if you have e.g. more that 2 methods to implement, `Enum` becomes not so comfortable to use; then you can switch into class hierarhy and do exactly like in enum (do not forget, the in JVM each constant in `Enum` is a different implementatino of `Enum` interface).

**P.S.** Your approach is not so bad, it is pretty usefule in many cases:

```
private void process(Animal animal) {
    if (animal instanceof Cat)
        process((Cat)animal);
    else if (animal instanceof Dog)
        process((Dog)animal);
    else
        System.out.println("unsopported animal");
}

private void process(Cat cat) {
    cat.getCatName();
}

private void process(Dog dog) {
    dog.getDogName();
}
```

Comment: That's... literally what he already had, except using method overloading instead of uniquely named methods.

Comment: @user69513 Not exactly. As I understand, he doesn't want to use `reflection`. I give example how to avoid it.

Comment: In his first code block, he doesn't use reflection. He then describes using reflection as a way to avoid the hard coded lookup table approach.

Comment: Maybe the asker doesn't understand about method overloading? this gives a good example, however I don't believe that the casting is necessary, if you provide a fallback Animal method.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach I agree. We have many different soulutions of this problem. I prefer to use `Enum`, in most cases it satisfied me.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Method overloading does not work at runtime in Java, only compile time (that is, it uses the statically determined type). This is different from inheritance, which uses virtual functions and dynamically dispatches them at runtime (I don't mean to sound condescending, it legitimately trips me up sometimes).

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Yup, [pretty sure](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/08au/java/subtypes.html). Or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1572371).

Comment: Guys, stop chatting, this is not a topic of this quetion.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik it's directly relevant, because it dictates what approaches will and won't work to solve it.

Comment: You can't change the function from `processCat() ` to `process()`. He says these are given and implemented. The problem is in Hierarchy and dynamic binding is impossible.

Comment: @user69513 I offer approach that works. You can accept it or not. That's all. I said, then there're many another correct approaches to solve the problem.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim You are not right. `processCat()` does not belong to the `Animal` insance and could be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [the answer provided by @RyanTheLeach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50690649) addresses your problem quite nicely, via a registry based approach. However, in comments to your question the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) was brought up. I mentioned "if you create the instances yourself", and... it's not currently elaborated on by any of the existing answers. I find that subtle variations of the problem you've encountered here tend to be annoyingly frequent. Since implementing a wrapper based visitor pattern in Java can be a bit confusing, I thought I'd add some details about that particular approach.

First off, this *seems* like it should be extremely simple. Just create a visitor interface, a wrapper for the base type, and a wrapper method accepting visitor implementations.

```
public interface AnimalVisitor {
    public void visit(Animal instance);
    public void visit(Cat instance);
    public void visit(Dog instance);
    // ...
}

public class AnimalWrapper {
    public final Animal instance;
    // ...
    public void acceptVisitor(AnimalVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(instance);
    }
}
```

Method overloading will take care of the rest, right? It turns out that this won't work, because [Java determines the method overload to call based on the statically determined type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1572371), as opposed to the actual type at runtime. Note that this is different from inheritance, where [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) is used to look up the concrete implementation of a [virtual method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) at runtime.

Perhaps we could tackle this with generics?

```
public class AnimalWrapper <T extends Animal> {
    public final T instance;
    // ...
    public void acceptVisitor(AnimalVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(instance);
    }
}
```

Nope. It might *seem* like the call to `visitor.visit(instance)` should statically determine the subtype, but in reality the static type of a generic is the upper bound of its capture (in this case, `Animal`).

Perhaps we could get around this by leveraging the usual Java pattern for obtaining [runtime type information for generics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3403987)?

```
public class AnimalWrapper <T extends Animal> {
    public final T instance;
    private final Class<T> type;
    // ...
    public void acceptVisitor(AnimalVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(type.cast(instance));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this won't work either, for the same reason as before; `Class<T> type` is also generic, so it statically resolves to the basetype `Animal`.

So how can we make this work? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39254583) illustrates quite clearly how to go about this using a separate wrapper class for every subtype you want to wrap. Wouldn't it be nice if we could pull this off without needing so many different unique wrapper classes though? You said you're using Java 8, so lets combine lambdas and static factory methods to achieve all of this more or less transparently (and with only a single wrapper class).

#### The Third-Party Code

```
public abstract class Animal {

    private final String instanceName;

    private Animal(String instanceName) {
        this.instanceName = instanceName;
    }

    public abstract String typeName();

    public String instanceName() {
        return instanceName;
    }

    public static class Cat extends Animal {

        public Cat(String instanceName) {
            super(instanceName);
        }

        @Override
        public String typeName() {
            return "Cat";
        }
    }

    public static class Dog extends Animal {

        public Dog(String instanceName) {
            super(instanceName);
        }

        @Override
        public String typeName() {
            return "Dog";
        }
    }

    public static class Fox extends Animal {

        public Fox(String instanceName) {
            super(instanceName);
        }

        @Override
        public String typeName() {
            return "Fox";
        }
    }
}
```

#### Our Code

```
/*
 * The Wrapper Class
 */
public class AnimalWrapper {

    private final Animal instance;
    private final Consumer<AnimalVisitor> visitResolver;

    private AnimalWrapper(Animal instance, Consumer<AnimalVisitor> visitResolver) {
        this.instance = instance;
        this.visitResolver = visitResolver;
    }

    public Animal getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void acceptVisitor(AnimalVisitor visitor) {
        visitResolver.accept(visitor);
    }

    public static AnimalWrapper create(Animal instance) {
        final Consumer<AnimalVisitor> visitResolver = visitor -> AnimalVisitor.visitResolver(visitor, instance);
        return new AnimalWrapper(instance, visitResolver);
    }

    public static AnimalWrapper create(Animal.Cat instance) {
        final Consumer<AnimalVisitor> visitResolver = visitor -> AnimalVisitor.visitResolver(visitor, instance);
        return new AnimalWrapper(instance, visitResolver);
    }

    public static AnimalWrapper create(Animal.Dog instance) {
        final Consumer<AnimalVisitor> visitResolver = visitor -> AnimalVisitor.visitResolver(visitor, instance);
        return new AnimalWrapper(instance, visitResolver);
    }

    public static AnimalWrapper create(Animal.Fox instance) {
        final Consumer<AnimalVisitor> visitResolver = visitor -> AnimalVisitor.visitResolver(visitor, instance);
        return new AnimalWrapper(instance, visitResolver);
    }
}

/*
 * The Visitor Interface
 */
public interface AnimalVisitor {

    public default void visit(Animal instance) {
        printMessage("Default implementation", "Animal (base type)", instance);
    }

    public static void visitResolver(AnimalVisitor visitor, Animal instance) {
        visitor.visit(instance);
    }

    public default void visit(Animal.Cat instance) {
        printMessage("Default implementation", "Cat", instance);
    }

    public static void visitResolver(AnimalVisitor visitor, Animal.Cat instance) {
        visitor.visit(instance);
    }

    public default void visit(Animal.Dog instance) {
        printMessage("Default implementation", "Dog", instance);
    }

    public static void visitResolver(AnimalVisitor visitor, Animal.Dog instance) {
        visitor.visit(instance);
    }

    public static void printMessage(String implementation, String signature, Animal instance) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(implementation);
        System.out.println("\tSignature: " + signature);
        System.out.println("\tInstance type: " + instance.typeName());
        System.out.println("\tInstance name: " + instance.instanceName());
    }
}

/*
 * The Visitor Implementation
 */
public class AnimalVisitorImpl implements AnimalVisitor {

    @Override
    public void visit(Animal instance) {
        AnimalVisitor.printMessage("Specialized implementation", "Animal (base type)", instance);
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Animal.Cat instance) {
        AnimalVisitor.printMessage("Specialized implementation", "Cat", instance);
    }
}

/*
 * Actual Usage
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<AnimalWrapper> wrappedAnimals = new ArrayList<>();
    wrappedAnimals.add(AnimalWrapper.create(new Animal.Cat("A normal cat.")));
    wrappedAnimals.add(AnimalWrapper.create((Animal) new Animal.Cat("A stealthy cat.")));
    wrappedAnimals.add(AnimalWrapper.create(new Animal.Dog("A dog (only default support).")));
    wrappedAnimals.add(AnimalWrapper.create(new Animal.Fox("A fox (no support).")));

    final AnimalVisitor visitor = new AnimalVisitorImpl();
    for (AnimalWrapper w : wrappedAnimals)
        w.acceptVisitor(visitor);
}
```

#### Output

```
Specialized implementation
    Signature: Cat
    Instance type: Cat
    Instance name: A normal cat.

Specialized implementation
    Signature: Animal (base type)
    Instance type: Cat
    Instance name: A stealthy cat.

Default implementation
    Signature: Dog
    Instance type: Dog
    Instance name: A dog (only default support).

Specialized implementation
    Signature: Animal (base type)
    Instance type: Fox
    Instance name: A fox (no support).
```

---

#### Other Thoughts

- The library ought to have provided a method accepting a visitor in the first place!
- All of this will only work if we are the ones instantiating the individual instances. As soon as we have to deal with receiving something opaque (such as a `Collection<Animal>`) from the third party code, this approach breaks down and we find ourselves back at a check-and-cast (or reflection) based approach. This is why the [registry based approach outlined by @RyanTheLeach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50690649) really shines; `animalInstance.getClass()` returns the unique static class object that is shared by all instances of that particular subtype, thereby allowing us to retrieve the correct lambda even when presented with a basetype instance.